# How to Modify VLOOKUP formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I need to Update Table _01 referring to Table _02.

The Expected results is shown in Table _ 03

But the results as shown in Table _ 04 when I Used the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(D4,A$17:B$21,2,0)
```

[consider the following case](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-d9z9oO5tJ6VHJIVm5BNWYtb3c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please consider editing your question to describe the problem more thoroughly to go with your image, in that way we can help you more easily and the question can help someone else in the future as links can break

Answer (score 0):

It's because the data source you reference in your vlookup (A$17:B$21) can't find some of the IDs as they don't exist in there, so it's showing the value as #N/A, aac for example is not an ID there. You should make a new table and try this instead (where you have table_04, put this formula in E4 and drag down):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,$A$17:$B$21,2,FALSE))=FALSE,(VLOOKUP(G4,$A$17:$B$21,2,FALSE)),(VLOOKUP(G4,$A$4:$B$12,2,FALSE)))
```

What I've basically done is create an IF statement that looks to see if an ID value exists in the new table. If it doesn't it then refers to the original table.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G4,$A$17:$B$21,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(G4,$A$4:$B$12,2,FALSE))
```